# How to convert an exception to another one using PostSharp?

Tags: c#, exception, aop, postsharp

I would like to automagically add the following code around the body of some methods:

```
try
{
   // method body
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   throw new MyException("Some appropriate message", e);
}
```

I am working with PostSharp 1.0 and this is what I've done at the moment:

```
public override void OnException(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    throw new MyException("Some appropriate message", eventArgs.Exception);
}
```

My problem is that I can see the PostSharp `OnException` call in the stack.
What would be the good practice to avoid this and get the same call stack as implementing by hand the exception handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things working in tandem will allow you to do this:

1. The fact that `Exception.StackTrace` is `virtual`
2. The use of the `skipFrames` parameter to the `StackFrame` constructor. This is not required, but makes things easier

The below example demonstrates how to customize the stack trace. Note that I know of no way to customize the `Exception.TargetSite` property, which still gives the details of the method from which the exception originated.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // exception is reported at method A, even though it is thrown by method B
            MethodA();
        }

        private static void MethodA()
        {
            MethodB();
        }

        private static void MethodB()
        {
            throw new MyException();
        }
    }

    public class MyException : Exception
    {
        private readonly string _stackTrace;

        public MyException()
        {
            // skip the top two frames, which would be this constructor and whoever called us
            _stackTrace = new StackTrace(2).ToString();
        }

        public override string StackTrace
        {
            get { return _stackTrace; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not 100% clean (TargetSite), but I like the hack. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to hide "OnException" from the call stack.

Comment: This was not an expected answer, but it is the most acurate one! Thanks.